# How can I build domain specific language models using Open-AI GPT for natural language generation?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, openai-gym, nlg, openai-universe

I want to build my own language model using Open-AI GPT. How can I build domain specific language models using Open-AI GPT for natural language generation?

Answer (score -1):

You have to fill out the [waitlist](https://share.hsforms.com/1Lfc7WtPLRk2ppXhPjcYY-A4sk30) form and be accepted by OpenAI.

More so than that however, you likely have to have an idea that is worthwhile for OpenAI to consider you, have a personal connection to the team, or a history of building interesting things within the field of Natural Language Generation.

There are tens of thousands of people who would like access to GPT-3, so you have to think carefully about why OpenAI would allow you as opposed to someone else access to a scarce resource. Do you have a PhD? Are you improving the world somehow? Will you make them tons of money? These are some of the possible considerations you may need to demonstrate when communicating your idea.